# Trying to do something really simple with iCloud using NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, icloud

So I am simply trying to get my Ubiquious key data thing working.  And unfortunately I have not been able too! I just cant get it to do anything with iCloud!

[Here](https://app.box.com/s/or8j6k0pkvirnqof5si9zc6l71zqeii3) is a project file that has a simple storyboard with three buttons.  The goal would be that you press the "upload button", wait a bit, delete the app, reinstall, press check, and the console prints out "IT WORKED".  However it seems to always print out "nil" indicating that iCloud isn't working!

The project contains basically no code.  It will only take you a second or two to read all of it.

You might have to change the bundle identifier and make a provisioning profile that accepts iCloud. Also make sure to activate iCloud in your "capabilities" section.

If you can manage to get this working or tell me what I am doing wrong it would be MUCH appreciated!  Here are some tutorials I used on this.

- [Tut1](http://www.ryanwright.me/cookbook/ios/obj-c/application-settings/icloud)
- [Tut2](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/sync-preference-data-with-icloud.html)
- [Tut3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=afSTsAdGcS0)
- [Tut4](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/iCloudFundametals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012094-CH6-SW13)
- [Tut5](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore_class/index.html)

Comment: Check the Apple [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PrefsInCloud/Introduction/Intro.html).

Comment: It works as is for me. How long are you waiting before deleting it?

Comment: @beyowulf about 30 seconds

Comment: I don't know if this is necessary, but try hitting upload, wait a second, leave the app, enter the app, hit check. See it's set. Then delete reinstall. Then check.

Comment: @beyowulf still not working for me....  Did you change any settings?  Or make your provisioning profile for it a special way?

Comment: No. Weirdly it works for me in the iPhone 6s+ simulator but not the iPhone 5s

Comment: @mundi the apple sample code works! However it doesn't function much differently then mine.....

Answer (score 0):

OK! So after i realized that the apple example worked I had a crazy thought.  I copied "$(TeamIdentifierPrefix)com.broccoli.sharedkvstore" from their entitlements file and put it into my projects entitlements file (technically i switched "yourcompanyname" with "broccoli").  And it worked!

A big thank you to @beowulf, and @mundi without whom I couldn't have fixed this.